# podspec with dependency to another ios framework project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I  had developed a `swift farmework` to share with other developers(Lets name it B). This framework is using another `ios framework project` that I created recently with `objective-c` (lets name it A).

Now, I want to share framework B with `cocoa pod`. I wondering how should I link these two project in the `podspec` file. Does I need to share both of them with `pod`? or is there any other solution that just share project B?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same question when I was trying to create a swift framework that is using obj-c framework, but didn't find an excellent solution.

So I've made a dependency in podspec file and now my swift framework can be installed by a podfile and it works fine. When I call pod install/update it installs/updates my framework and a dependency framework

The dependency can be created by one line

> spec.dependency 'SomeOtherPod'

Check this link https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Also you can check [my podspec](https://github.com/BlindDev/PVPMikrotikSSH/blob/master/PVPMikrotikSSH.podspec)

The only thing that I don't like is that I have one warning in my project now:

> Multiple build commands for output file
> ..../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NMSSH/NMSSH.framework/Headers/NMSSH.h

Still trying to find how to solve it

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1. Distribute both pods and use spec.dependency in your podspec file (see Woof's answer)
2. Add A source files directly to B's source files