# Error while doing lint command on private pod "Encountered an unknown error (no implicit conversion of nil into String) during validation."

Tags: swift, cocoapods, private, lint, podspec

I'm creating a private pod depending on another private pod the linter works well when I don't add any dependency but when I add the dependency and run the lint command it gives me that error

```
Encountered an unknown error (no implicit conversion of nil into String) during validation.
```

the lint commmand:

```
pod spec lint --private --sources=https://github.com/*****/****.git
```

Here is my podSpec what is wrong with it and what should I do to fix that?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name         = "****Framework"
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.summary      = "Summary  ................."
s.homepage     = "https://github.com/****/****Framework"
s.description  = "Description ................."
s.license      = "Simplified BSD license"
s.author       = { "Nahla Mortada" => "nahla.mortada@****.com" }
s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
s.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"
s.source   = { :git => "https://github.com/****/****Framework.git", :tag => s.version }
s.source_files = "****Framework/*.swift"
s.pod_target_xcconfig =  {
'SWIFT_VERSION' => '3.0',
}
s.requires_arc = true
s.dependency '****'

end
```

Full Error:

```
ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (no implicit conversion of nil into String
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:531:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:531:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:531:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:45:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:265:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:347:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:317:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:290:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:108:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:206:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:200:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:200:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:446:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:438:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:422:in `activate_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:388:in `attempt_to_activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:319:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:137:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:78:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.5.5/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:62:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:719:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:717:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:76:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:149:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:405:in `block in download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:405:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:405:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:301:in `block in perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:295:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:295:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:79:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:64:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:53:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:53:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
) during validation.
```

Comment: Add the --verbose option to learn more

Comment: updated the question but still don't understand what's wrong

Comment: The dependency which is private is supposed to be where exactly? A private repo? Did you try to add ":git" or something like that? Because if it's private an unknown, it still need to fetch it. Maybe look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905112/cocoapods-dependency-in-pod-spec-not-working

Comment: I'm creating cocoapod :git is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your local CocoaPods cache by running `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and then running `pod setup`.

Your `podspec` appears to be valid, if this doesn't help you should try uncommenting your `s.dependency` und linting it again, because the dependency-pod might also be the one causing this crash.

Comment: Yes it is the one doing that but the dependency pod is valid and we use it in different projects. I did what you said and still the same error